# How to use canvas.drawCircle with Scale Detector

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I used the below code. It works fine but i need to draw the circle instead of image. Below code is with the image(drawable) but i need to draw circe using cnvas.drawCircle(). Plz show me a way to do this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
 import android.view.View;

public class MyImageView extends View {

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

private Drawable mImage;
private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

public MyImageView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
mImage=act.getResources().getDrawable(context.getResources().getIdentifier("imag­ename", "drawable", "packagename"));

    mImage.setBounds(0, 0, mImage.getIntrinsicWidth(), mImage.getIntrinsicHeight());
}

public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;
        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
        final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
        final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

        // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
        if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            mPosX += dx;
            mPosY += dy;

            invalidate();
        }

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
            mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    Log.d("DEBUG", "X: "+mPosX+" Y: "+mPosY);
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    mImage.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: what problems do you have with Canvas.drawCircle ?

Comment: to drawCircle i need cX and cY ? How can i get that?

Comment: You dont know where you want to draw a circle?